# INDEX MACTH [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a table with the result of a test. The table is structured as follows:

```
student   score_description   score_value
Juan           test 1              5
Peter       
Brian          test 2              8
Jose           test3              10
```

I need to convert this into a kind of pivot table using only formulas. For this, I thought of using the INDEX & Match but it doesn't work. At the end, I should see something like this:

```
student   test1   test2   test3
Juan        5       
Peter           
Brian               8   
Jose                       10
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A,sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B ")
```

or

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A,sum(C) where B is not null group by A pivot B ")
```

[image]